# Is it possible to annotate a column which contains a queryset?

Tags: django, django-queryset

I want to show a table on a HTML template with data from GroupCaseFile model. But one of the columns must contain data from the most recent ProceduralAct object, specifically: 'act_number', 'act_type', and 'act_summary' (inside a single cell of the HTML table).

I could simply use something like this to get it:

`group_case_file.case_file.proceduralact_set.all().order_by('-created_at').first()`

But, before getting the last ProceduralAct, I want to apply filtering by search term. The search term should cover 'act_number', 'act_type', and 'act_summary' from the corresponding last ProceduralAct.

To be able to do this search, I have tried using nested subqueries, like I did with 'summary' on the code below, to annotate 'summary' value in the GroupCaseFile query, and only then apply the filtering by search term. I think this would be enough if I wanted to get search only 'summary'.

But I want to know if there is any way to annotate a column, let's say `last_procedural_act`, which can contain a QuerySet of the corresponding most recent ProceduralAct row. That way, I could perform search on all of the fields of that ProceduralAct row

I'd appreciate if there is a different approach for this.

Models

```
class CaseFile(models.Model):

    code = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=30)
    # More fields

class GroupCaseFile(models.Model):

    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    case_file = models.ForeignKey(
        CaseFile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    group = models.ForeignKey('accounts.Group', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    client_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    # More fields

class ProceduralAct(models.Model):

   id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
   case_file = models.ForeignKey(
       CaseFile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
   act_type = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   act_number = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
   summary = models.TextField()
   created_at = models.DateField()
```

Part of the view

```
# A subquery to retrieve the summary of the latest procedural act
subquery_procedural_acts_summary = Subquery(
    ProceduralAct.objects.filter(
        casefile=OuterRef('pk')
    ).order_by('-created_at').values('summary')[:1]
)

# A subquery to retrieve the last procedural act with its summary
subquery_case_file_last_procedural_act_summary = Subquery(
    CaseFile.objects.annotate(
        last_procedural_act_summary=subquery_procedural_acts_summary
    ).filter(
        groupcasefile=OuterRef('pk')
    ).values('last_procedural_act_summary')
)

# Add columns with data from each data of the last procedural act
group_case_files = GroupCaseFile.objects.annotate(
    last_procedural_act_summary=subquery_case_file_last_procedural_act_summary
) # Do filtering by search terms

dashboard_case_files_list = []
for group_case_file in group_case_files:
   # Collect data to send it as context
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly annotate a queryset or whole model, but this what I can suggest.

**Approach 1 - filter in iteration**

*I could simply use something like this to get it:*

`group_case_file.case_file.proceduralact_set.all().order_by('-created_at').first()`

*But, before getting the last ProceduralAct, I want to apply filtering by search term.*

You can add filter before calling `first()`:

`group_case_file.case_file.proceduralact_set.all().order_by('-created_at').filter().first()`

But this approach will lead to N+1 problem which affects on performance.

**Approach 2 - prefetch custom queryset**

It's possible to prefetch filtered `ProceduralAct` by search term and then take only first in iteration. It's not the best option, because we prefetch all `ProceduralAct` instead of taking only first of them, but it still better than first approach.

```
procedural_act_query = ProceduralAct.objects.order_by("-created_at").filter(
    # Any other filters on any field
)


group_case_file_query = GroupCaseFile.objects.prefetch_related(
    models.Prefetch(
        lookup="case_file__proceduralact_set",
        queryset=procedural_act_query,
    )
)

for group_case_file in group_case_file_query:
    # Getting a first item in queryset
    latest_act = list(group_case_file.case_file.proceduralact_set.all())[0]
```

**Approach 3 - window function**

If I'm not mistaken, it's possible to filter queryset and use window function to take only latest `ProceduralAct` for each `CaseFile`. It's similar to the second approach, but here we will prefetch only latest objects after applying a filter.

```
procedural_act_query = ProceduralAct.objects.filter(
    id__in=ProceduralAct.objects.annotate(
        row_n=models.Window(
            expression=RowNumber(),
            partition_by="case_file",
            order_by=models.F("created_at").desc(),
        )
    )
    .filter(
        # Search filters here. It's important to make filters in this subquery
        # because we want search and take latest acts after that search.
        # In other case, search term filter must be in outer queryset.
    )
    .filter(row_n=1)
    .values("id"),
)


group_case_file_query = GroupCaseFile.objects.prefetch_related(
    models.Prefetch(
        lookup="case_file__proceduralact_set",
        queryset=procedural_act_query,
    )
)

for group_case_file in group_case_file_query:
    # Getting a first item in queryset
    latest_act = list(group_case_file.case_file.proceduralact_set.all())[0]
```